# How can I shorten strings shown in the i3status bar?

Tags: cut, i3

I am using the [i3status bar](http://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html). In the bar, I am displaying my wireless network details. However, space is limited and this takes up a whole lot of it. The standard format is defined in the `i3status.conf` file and is the following:

> format_up = "%ip (%quality @ %essid)"

Which translates to:

> 123.123.123.123 (64% at Our Turbo Network)

I rather have only a fragment of this available, something like this:

> .123 (64% at Our T)

So the last 4 characters of the IP and the first 5 of the network name. I've tried using `cut` in the i3status.conf file, but that didn't work. Are there any easy ways of getting this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `i3status` man page, section titled "EXTERNAL SCRIPTS/PROGRAMS WITH I3STATUS", you can set the `bar` section of the `.i3/config` file to a shell script you write. They give an example in the man page, and further examples are at http://code.i3wm.org/i3status/tree/contrib. Looks to me like you could take the example shell script from the man page, and trigger it up to do what you describe.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed is an option. But given that the wireless connection information is already built-in, it seems quite a workaround which I hoped to avoid. If there is any way to use `cut` or whatever other mechanism to shorten the string within the regular i3status config, that would be really helpful.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme - I think you're out of luck. If you read the `i3status` man page, the author(s) explicitly write that they didn't want to reimplement job control, so there's no way to do what you ask. Sorry.